# .NET MVC website Deployment

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-2, windows-server-2008

Strange thing is happing with my .NET MVC deployment.

I have tested my application on my development environment, and on IIS of my Win7 and every works as expected.

But after deployed my application on Windows Server 2008, Login/Authentication page appear, on almost every pages, even to access 'scripts' and 'contents' folders.

Any tips of whats I did wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was a real pain on the neck, but after several days I found out the problem.

The problem was solved by setting the correct user on  Application Pool, in IIS.